# product.info block does not move in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

**product.info** block does not move in my custom container in **catalog_product_view.xml** file
I have try

```
<move element="product.info" destination="product.test" after="-"  />

<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container name="product.test" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-test" >
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

But not working.

I have try

```
<move element="product.info.review" destination="product.test" after="-"/>
```

This is work perfect.

Thanks.